# How do I change specific worksheet to current worksheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I've a command button with a macro attached in workbook A that copies cells `A2:B2` from any workbook in a folder and pastes them starting at cell `B2` in the `AMT` worksheet also in workbook A.

I'd like to place a command button on every worksheet and Instead of always pasting to the `AMT` worksheet I'd like to paste to whichever worksheet the command button was clicked on.

This is how I've been transferring the data from one sheet to another so far but I'm not sure how to change `AMT` to `worksheet macro was clicked on` I've been warned about using `.Select` and `.Activate` but I'm not sure how else to do this, thanks.

```
 'Transfer cells B2 & C2 from the results worksheet
                 With ws.Range("A2:B2")
                     ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AMT").Range("B4").Offset(wbc, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
                 End With
```

Comment: Look into [ActiveSheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.activesheet)

Comment: Look into `Application.Caller` then, I think you can get the parent property to find the location of the command button. (I may be wrong, but give it a shot). It's a little cleaner then `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: Looking into both now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do active sheet, you could set some cell to change, for example from a 0 to 1 after the click and then loop through each sheet to see which range was changed to pull the value you want.